# how to create new table in mysql with date default value for current date?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I am trying the following code:

```
create table People (
  first_name varchar(15) not null,
  last_name varchar(15) not null,
  registration_date date not null);
```

How can I make a default value for the date column? try the `now()`, but it is not valid..

Comment: Try `current_date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `current_date`

```
create table People (
    first_name varchar(15) not null,
    last_name varchar(15) not null,
    registration_date date not null DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, I tested on MySQL 8.0.27.

```
mysql> create table People (
  first_name varchar(15) not null,
  last_name varchar(15) not null,
  registration_date date not null default (current_date));
```

Note the parentheses around the default expression. This is required.

```
mysql> insert into People (first_name, last_name) values ('Bill', 'Karwin');

mysql> select * from People;
+------------+-----------+-------------------+
| first_name | last_name | registration_date |
+------------+-----------+-------------------+
| Bill       | Karwin    | 2022-01-13        |
+------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Expressions as column defaults is a new feature introduced in MySQL 8.0.13, so it won't work in older versions of MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html for more information.